# Deploy with capistrano through sftp (no ssh available)

Tags: capistrano, sftp

I was wondering if it is possible to deploy a rail application to an host for which I only have sftp access. (No ssh access, unfortunately).

I found this page,

http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/1271

which it makes me think it could be done, although it really is not clear with me what I should do with such file, nor whether this also enables also cap deploy:setup through sftp... Any suggestions please? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I found that the code snippet is to be put in $GEM_HOME/capistrano-2.5.19/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/strategy/sftp_copy.rb    --  The problem is that `cap deploy:setup` still tries to access the remote host via ssh instead of sftp.